# Use the event handler "on message" for all signals and not for a defined one

Tags: can-bus, capl

I would like to use to an event for every CAN message in CAPL. I mean by that to have the same event for every CAN message sent. Is it possible to do it with the structure "on message"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an asterisk:

```c
/* event handler for all received messages */
on message *
{
    output(this);
}
```

or

```c
/* event handler for all messages received on CAN1 */
on message CAN1.*
{
    // ...    
}
```